# Laravel 4 - DB::select returns array but not found $array[$key]

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-4

In laravel 4 route, i have a database query like this

```
$data1 = DB::select('SELECT MAX(id) AS mxid FROM table_name', array());
return $data1["mxid"];
```

But it gives the following error:

[image]

Help me. I can't understand why this key is not found . If i  write

```
return $data1;
```

it gives,

```
[{"mxid":"0"}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

```
return $data1[0]->mxid;
```

Comment: Hey, i was stuck on the same thing. How do you count the number of rows the query fetches?

Answer (score 3):

You could leverage the query builder to make this slightly easier and nicer looking.

```
return DB::table('table_name')->selectRaw('MAX(id) AS mxid')->pluck('mxid');
```

This should pluck the `mxid` column from the result and return it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting "Trying to get property of non-object" error. Any idea?

EDIT:

This solved the problem for me:

```
return $result[0]['field_name'];
```